# Why is my Scene null?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying to do some 3D work with Javafx (using the TornadoFX library) and am unable to set my `PerspectiveCamera` to the `Scene` as the `Scene` is returning `null`.

I launch my program like so:

```
class ThreeDTest : App(HomeView::class, ThreeDStyles::class) {
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        super.start(stage)
        stage.show()
        stage.scene.fill = Color.BLACK

        val primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().visualBounds

        stage.maxWidth = 1920.0
        stage.maxHeight = 1080.0
        stage.minWidth = 1920.0
        stage.minHeight = 1080.0
    }
}
```

and then in `HomeView` class I have this:

```
class HomeView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        val axisGroup = Xform()
        val world = Xform()
        val camera = PerspectiveCamera(true)
        val cameraXform = Xform()
        val cameraXform2 = Xform()
        val cameraXform3 = Xform()
        val cameraInitialDistance = -450.0
        val cameraInitialXAngle = 70.0
        val cameraInitialYAngle = 320.0
        val cameraNearClip = 0.1
        val cameraFarClip = 10000.0

        //just a builder class to add properties to the camera
        buildCamera(this, cameraXform, cameraXform2, cameraXform3, camera, cameraNearClip, cameraFarClip, cameraInitialDistance,
            cameraInitialYAngle, cameraInitialXAngle)
        buildAxes(axisGroup, world)

        println(scene)
        //returns null
        scene.camera = camera
        //this does not work as scene is null
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I have no idea why my `Scene` is null as I thought TornadoFX `View` was supposed to create a new `Scene` when it's initialized? Do I need to manually create it in the App class? I tried overriding the `createPrimaryScene` function, and also moving my code to an `init` function within the `HomeView` view– both with no success.

Any ideas? Pulling out hairs over here.

(Oh, and on an unrelated note, could I just say that having 3D support in TornadoFX would, quite frankly, make my *entire life*?)

Comment: We'll definitely look into creating 3D builders for TornadoFX :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The View is created before the scene is attached, so to manipulate scene, simply override `onDock` and perform your operations there. When `onDock` is called, the scene is attached.

Comment: My pleasure! :)